# Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

Hello Fellows when i was trying to add the admob SDK i got this error :

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller
```

- I've tried
- Invalidating cache
- cleaning and rebuilding
- using ./gradlew build --stacktrace --info command

but without success.

**This is what im getting every time :**

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller
```

**Here are my app build.grable :**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ar.rulosoft.mimanganu"
        versionCode 92
        versionName "1.92"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        minSdkVersion 15
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../mimanganu.jks")
            storePassword 'mimanganu'
            keyAlias 'mimanganu'
            keyPassword 'mimanganu'
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file("../mimanganu.jks")
            storePassword 'mimanganu'
            keyAlias 'mimanganu'
            keyPassword 'mimanganu'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                disable 'NewApi' //Avoid problems in Android Studio 2.4 preview 6
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    flavorDimensions "builds"
    productFlavors {
        fdroid {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            versionNameSuffix '-fdroid'
            dimension "builds"
        }
        github {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
             //removed to maintain updates as now are
            dimension "builds"
        }
    }
}

android.sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/testShare"
    }

    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/testShare"
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}

dependencies {
    final ANDROID_SUPPORT = '28.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$ANDROID_SUPPORT"
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$ANDROID_SUPPORT"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$ANDROID_SUPPORT"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$ANDROID_SUPPORT"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:$ANDROID_SUPPORT"
    api project(':imageviewtouchlibrary')
    implementation 'rapid.decoder:library:0.3.0'
    implementation 'rapid.decoder:jpeg-decoder:0.3.0'
    implementation 'rapid.decoder:png-decoder:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0' //on 3.10.0 are deprecated some ciphers
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.duktape:duktape-android:1.3.0'/* v 1.2.0 need 4+mb extra*/
    implementation 'com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.5'
    githubImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
    // ADDED BY O D I N
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    // ADDED BY O D I N
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
    fdroidApi project(':fakegps')
    // for device-based testing
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$ANDROID_SUPPORT"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // for host-based testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-beta-1'

    android {
        testOptions {
            unitTests {
                includeAndroidResources = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Project's build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        // ADDED BY O D I N
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        // ADDED BY O D I N


        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder/raw/master/repository'
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

after so many attempt to add the SDK i still can't find any solution for this, Hope i find it here

Comment: Try : Delete all directories in app/build and re-open project.

Comment: Done and not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }` to your Project build.gradle. Like below. This fixed it for me.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
       maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Multidex support prior to Android 5.0

```
 dependencies {
        def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version'
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same kind of error : `com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: [com.some.lib]`.

After dumping all the dependencies in console (via `./gradlew dependencies > ./dept.txt`), I found out a new added aar does contain the same  dependent library as reported above, so just exclude that out. It's done.

```
implementation ('the-new-library') {
    transitive = true
    exclude group : 'duplicate-lib-pkg', module:"duplicate-lib-name"
}
```